# Calculate the distance between coordinates and insert in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, distance

Friends, could you help me to insert the distance between coordinates in my shiny. Basically my shiny has a sliderInput that corresponds to the desired number of clusters, followed by an option of which cluster he wants to see on the map, and the second option which industry of the selected cluster he wants to see. So far it is working properly. Note that on the map there is always a location point and an industry, because for the generation of the map I am joining database df with database df1. However, I would like to add another feature, which is to calculate the distance between this location point and the industry. I inserted an attached image to better illustrate my idea. The distance calculation formula that I believe is the one I inserted below too, I just need help for shiny to display the distance in the textInput (Filter3) that I made.  If not to be textInput it can be another way too. So, whenever he selects a cluster and the industry, I intend to show the distance between them too. The executable code is below.

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(shinythemes)
library(leaflet)


function.cl<-function(df,k,Filter1,Filter2,Filter3){

  df<-structure(list(Industries = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
                     Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.7, -23.7,-23.7), 
                     Longitude = c(-49.5, -49.6, -49.7, -49.8, -49.6,-49.9), 
                     Waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 534, 346)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

  #clusters
  coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
  fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k) 
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))  
  df$cluster <- clusters 

  #Center of mass
  center_mass<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=2)
  for(i in 1:k){
    center_mass[i,]<-c(weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Latitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste),
                       weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Longitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste))}
  coordinates$cluster<-clusters 
  center_mass<-cbind(center_mass,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1)) 

  #Coverage
  coverage<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=1)
  for(i in 1:k){
    aux_dist<-distm(rbind(subset(coordinates,cluster==i),center_mass[i,])[,2:1])
    coverage[i,]<-max(aux_dist[nclusters[i,1]+1,])}
  coverage<-cbind(coverage,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1))
  colnames(coverage)<-c("Coverage_meters","cluster")

  #Sum of Waste from clusters
  sum_waste<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=1)
  for(i in 1:k){
    sum_waste[i,]<-sum(subset(df,cluster==i)["Waste"])
  }
  sum_waste<-cbind(sum_waste,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1))
  colnames(sum_waste)<-c("Potential_Waste_m3","cluster")

  #Tables to join information above and generate df1
  data_table <- Reduce(merge, list(df, coverage,sum_waste))
  data_table <- data_table[order(data_table$cluster, as.numeric(data_table$Industries)),]
  data_table_1 <- aggregate(. ~ cluster + Coverage_meters + Potential_Waste_m3, data_table[,c(1,5,6,7)], toString)
  df1<-as.data.frame(center_mass)
  colnames(df1) <-c("Latitude", "Longitude", "cluster")

  #specific cluster and specific propertie
  df_spec_clust <- df1[df1$cluster == Filter1,]
  df_spec_prop<-df[df$Industries==Filter2,]


  #Color and Icon for map
  ai_colors <-c("red","gray","blue","orange","green","beige","darkgreen","lightgreen", "lightred", "darkblue","lightblue",
                "purple","darkpurple","pink", "cadetblue","white","darkred", "lightgray","black")
  clust_colors <- ai_colors[df$cluster]
  icons <- awesomeIcons(
    icon = 'ios-close',
    iconColor = 'black',
    library = 'ion',
    markerColor =  clust_colors)

  leafIcons <- icons(
    iconUrl = ifelse(df1$Industries,
                     "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/542/542461.svg"
    ),
    iconWidth = 45, iconHeight = 40,
    iconAnchorX = 25, iconAnchorY = 12)
  html_legend <- "<img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/542/542461.svg'>"

  # Map for specific cluster and propertie
  if(nrow(df_spec_clust)>0){
    clust_colors <- ai_colors[df_spec_clust$cluster]
    icons <- awesomeIcons(
      icon = 'ios-close',
      iconColor = 'black',
      library = 'ion',
      markerColor =  clust_colors)

  m1<-leaflet(df_spec_clust) %>% addTiles() %>%
    addMarkers(~Longitude, ~Latitude, icon = leafIcons) %>%
    addAwesomeMarkers(leaflet(df_spec_prop) %>% addTiles(), lat=~df_spec_prop$Latitude, lng = ~df_spec_prop$Longitude, icon= icons,label=~cluster)#%>%
  plot1<-m1} else plot1 <- NULL



  return(list(
    "Plot1" = plot1,
    "Data" = data_table_1,
    "Data1" = data_table
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Solution",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          tags$b(h3("Choose the cluster number?")),
                          sliderInput("Slider", h5(""),
                                      min = 2, max = 4, value = 3),
                          selectInput("Filter1", label = h4("Select just one cluster to show"),""),
                          selectInput("Filter2",label=h4("Select the cluster property designated above"),""),
                          textInput("Filter3", label = h4("Distance is:"), value = "Enter text..."),
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                            tabPanel("Solution", (leafletOutput("Leaf",width = "95%", height = "600"))))),
                      ))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Modelcl<-reactive({
    function.cl(df,input$Slider,input$Filter1,input$Filter2,input$Filter3)
  })


  output$Leaf <- renderLeaflet({
    Modelcl()[[1]]
  })

  observeEvent(c(df,input$Slider),{
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data)
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter1',
                      choices=c(sort(unique(abc$cluster)))) 
  }) 

  observeEvent(c(df,input$Slider,input$Filter1),{
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data1) %>% filter(cluster == as.numeric(input$Filter1))   
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter2',
                      choices = unique(abc$Industries))

})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolution for the question**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(shinythemes)
library(leaflet)


function.cl<-function(df,k,Filter1,Filter2,Filter3){

  df<-structure(list(Industries = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
                     Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.7, -23.7,-23.7), 
                     Longitude = c(-49.5, -49.6, -49.7, -49.8, -49.6,-49.9), 
                     Waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 534, 346)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
  k=3
  #clusters
  coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
  fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k) 
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))  
  df$cluster <- clusters 

  #Center of mass
  center_mass<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=2)
  for(i in 1:k){
    center_mass[i,]<-c(weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Latitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste),
                       weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Longitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste))}
  coordinates$cluster<-clusters 
  center_mass<-cbind(center_mass,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1)) 

  #Coverage
  coverage<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=1)
  for(i in 1:k){
    aux_dist<-distm(rbind(subset(coordinates,cluster==i),center_mass[i,])[,2:1])
    coverage[i,]<-max(aux_dist[nclusters[i,1]+1,])}
  coverage<-cbind(coverage,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1))
  colnames(coverage)<-c("Coverage_meters","cluster")

  #Sum of Waste from clusters
  sum_waste<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=1)
  for(i in 1:k){
    sum_waste[i,]<-sum(subset(df,cluster==i)["Waste"])
  }
  sum_waste<-cbind(sum_waste,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1))
  colnames(sum_waste)<-c("Potential_Waste_m3","cluster")

  #Tables to join information above and generate df1
  data_table <- Reduce(merge, list(df, coverage,sum_waste))
  data_table <- data_table[order(data_table$cluster, as.numeric(data_table$Industries)),]
  data_table_1 <- aggregate(. ~ cluster + Coverage_meters + Potential_Waste_m3, data_table[,c(1,5,6,7)], toString)
  df1<-as.data.frame(center_mass)
  colnames(df1) <-c("Latitude", "Longitude", "cluster")

  #specific cluster and specific propertie
  df_spec_clust <- df1[df1$cluster == Filter1,]
  df_spec_prop<-df[df$Industries==Filter2,]


  #Color and Icon for map
  ai_colors <-c("red","gray","blue","orange","green","beige","darkgreen","lightgreen", "lightred", "darkblue","lightblue",
                "purple","darkpurple","pink", "cadetblue","white","darkred", "lightgray","black")
  clust_colors <- ai_colors[df$cluster]
  icons <- awesomeIcons(
    icon = 'ios-close',
    iconColor = 'black',
    library = 'ion',
    markerColor =  clust_colors)

  leafIcons <- icons(
    iconUrl = ifelse(df1$Industries,
                     "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/542/542461.svg"
    ),
    iconWidth = 45, iconHeight = 40,
    iconAnchorX = 25, iconAnchorY = 12)
  html_legend <- "<img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/542/542461.svg'>"

  # Map for specific cluster and propertie
  if(nrow(df_spec_clust)>0){
    clust_colors <- ai_colors[df_spec_clust$cluster]
    icons <- awesomeIcons(
      icon = 'ios-close',
      iconColor = 'black',
      library = 'ion',
      markerColor =  clust_colors)

    m1<-leaflet(df_spec_clust) %>% addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers(~Longitude, ~Latitude, icon = leafIcons) %>%
      addAwesomeMarkers(leaflet(df_spec_prop) %>% addTiles(), lat=~df_spec_prop$Latitude, lng = ~df_spec_prop$Longitude, icon= icons,label=~cluster)#%>%
    plot1<-m1} else plot1 <- NULL


  mydf<- merge(df,df1,by = c("cluster"), suffixes = c("_df","_df1"))

  (mydf$distances <- purrr::pmap_dbl(.l = list(mydf$Longitude_df,
                                                     mydf$Latitude_df,
                                                     mydf$Longitude_df1,
                                                     mydf$Latitude_df1),
                                           .f = ~distm(c(..1,..2),c(..3,..4))))

  return(list(
    "Plot1" = plot1,
    "Data" = data_table_1,
    "Data1" = data_table,
    "Cover" = mydf
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Solution",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          tags$b(h3("Choose the cluster number?")),
                          sliderInput("Slider", h5(""),
                                      min = 2, max = 4, value = 3),
                          selectInput("Filter1", label = h4("Select just one cluster to show"),""),
                          selectInput("Filter2",label=h4("Select the cluster property designated above"),""),
                          h4("Distance is:"),
                          textOutput("dist"),
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                            tabPanel("Solution", (leafletOutput("Leaf",width = "95%", height = "600"))))),
                      ))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Modelcl<-reactive({
    function.cl(df,input$Slider,input$Filter1,input$Filter2,input$Filter3)
  })


  output$Leaf <- renderLeaflet({
    Modelcl()[[1]]
  })

  observeEvent(c(df,input$Slider),{
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data)
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter1',
                      choices=c(sort(unique(abc$cluster)))) 
  }) 

  observeEvent(c(df,input$Slider,input$Filter1),{
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data1) %>% filter(cluster == as.numeric(input$Filter1))   
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter2',
                      choices = unique(abc$Industries))

  })
  output$dist <- renderText({
    cover <- data.frame(Modelcl()[[4]])
    cover$distances[cover$cluster == input$Filter1 & cover$Industries == input$Filter2]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I understood everything correctly, but please elaborate if I missed something.

Assuming this bit of code does the distance calculation you need:

```
#Coverage
  coverage<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=1)
  for(i in 1:k){
    aux_dist<-distm(rbind(subset(coordinates,cluster==i),center_mass[i,])[,2:1])
    coverage[i,]<-max(aux_dist[nclusters[i,1]+1,])}
  coverage<-cbind(coverage,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1))
  colnames(coverage)<-c("Coverage_meters","cluster")
```

Then you need to return the coverage matrix along with the other elements:

```
  return(list(
    "Plot1" = plot1,
    "Data" = data_table_1,
    "Data1" = data_table,
    "Cover" = coverage
  ))
```

and index that matrix dependent on `input$Filter1` in the server:

```
  output$dist <- renderText({
    cover <- data.frame(Modelcl()[[4]])
    cover$Coverage_meters[cover$cluster == input$Filter1]
  })
```

Note that you don't need `input$Filter3`. This is only if you expect the user to input a distance? But if the goal is to display the distance, you need to replace that input with something like:

```
h4("Distance is:"),
textOutput("dist"),
```

Then we get something like this:

[image]

**Edit**

To index `Data1` instead of `Cover`, use the following `renderText`:

```
output$dist <- renderText({
    data1 <- data.frame(Modelcl()[[3]])
    data1$Coverage_meters[data1$cluster == input$Filter1 & data1$Industries == input$Filter2]
  })
```

---

Full code:

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(rdist)
library(geosphere)
library(shinythemes)
library(leaflet)


function.cl<-function(df,k,Filter1,Filter2){

  df<-structure(list(Industries = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), 
                     Latitude = c(-23.8, -23.8, -23.9, -23.7, -23.7,-23.7), 
                     Longitude = c(-49.5, -49.6, -49.7, -49.8, -49.6,-49.9), 
                     Waste = c(526, 350, 526, 469, 534, 346)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

  #clusters
  coordinates<-df[c("Latitude","Longitude")]
  d<-as.dist(distm(coordinates[,2:1]))
  fit.average<-hclust(d,method="average") 
  clusters<-cutree(fit.average, k) 
  nclusters<-matrix(table(clusters))  
  df$cluster <- clusters 

  #Center of mass
  center_mass<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=2)
  for(i in 1:k){
    center_mass[i,]<-c(weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Latitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste),
                       weighted.mean(subset(df,cluster==i)$Longitude,subset(df,cluster==i)$Waste))}
  coordinates$cluster<-clusters 
  center_mass<-cbind(center_mass,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1)) 

  #Coverage
  coverage <- matrix(nrow = k, ncol = 1)
  for (i in 1:k) {
    aux_dist <-
      distm(rbind(subset(coordinates, cluster == i), center_mass[i, ])[, 2:1])
    coverage[i, ] <- max(aux_dist[nclusters[i, 1] + 1, ])
  }
  coverage <- cbind(coverage, matrix(c(1:k), ncol = 1))
  colnames(coverage) <- c("Coverage_meters", "cluster")

  #Sum of Waste from clusters
  sum_waste<-matrix(nrow=k,ncol=1)
  for(i in 1:k){
    sum_waste[i,]<-sum(subset(df,cluster==i)["Waste"])
  }
  sum_waste<-cbind(sum_waste,matrix(c(1:k),ncol=1))
  colnames(sum_waste)<-c("Potential_Waste_m3","cluster")

  #Tables to join information above and generate df1
  data_table <- Reduce(merge, list(df, coverage,sum_waste))
  data_table <- data_table[order(data_table$cluster, as.numeric(data_table$Industries)),]
  data_table_1 <- aggregate(. ~ cluster + Coverage_meters + Potential_Waste_m3, data_table[,c(1,5,6,7)], toString)
  df1<-as.data.frame(center_mass)
  colnames(df1) <-c("Latitude", "Longitude", "cluster")

  #specific cluster and specific propertie
  df_spec_clust <- df1[df1$cluster == Filter1,]
  df_spec_prop<-df[df$Industries==Filter2,]


  #Color and Icon for map
  ai_colors <-c("red","gray","blue","orange","green","beige","darkgreen","lightgreen", "lightred", "darkblue","lightblue",
                "purple","darkpurple","pink", "cadetblue","white","darkred", "lightgray","black")
  clust_colors <- ai_colors[df$cluster]
  icons <- awesomeIcons(
    icon = 'ios-close',
    iconColor = 'black',
    library = 'ion',
    markerColor =  clust_colors)

  leafIcons <- icons(
    iconUrl = ifelse(df1$Industries,
                     "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/542/542461.svg"
    ),
    iconWidth = 45, iconHeight = 40,
    iconAnchorX = 25, iconAnchorY = 12)
  html_legend <- "<img src='https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/542/542461.svg'>"

  # Map for specific cluster and propertie
  if (nrow(df_spec_clust) > 0) {
    clust_colors <- ai_colors[df_spec_clust$cluster]
    icons <- awesomeIcons(
      icon = 'ios-close',
      iconColor = 'black',
      library = 'ion',
      markerColor =  clust_colors
    )

    m1 <- leaflet(df_spec_clust) %>% addTiles() %>%
      addMarkers( ~ Longitude, ~ Latitude, icon = leafIcons) %>%
      addAwesomeMarkers(
        leaflet(df_spec_prop) %>% addTiles(),
        lat =  ~ df_spec_prop$Latitude,
        lng = ~ df_spec_prop$Longitude,
        icon = icons,
        label =  ~ cluster
      )#%>%
    plot1 <- m1
  } else
    plot1 <- NULL



  return(list(
    "Plot1" = plot1,
    "Data" = data_table_1,
    "Data1" = data_table,
    "Cover" = coverage
  ))
}

ui <- bootstrapPage(
  navbarPage(theme = shinytheme("flatly"), collapsible = TRUE,
             "Cl", 
             tabPanel("Solution",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          tags$b(h3("Choose the cluster number?")),
                          sliderInput("Slider", h5(""),
                                      min = 2, max = 4, value = 3),
                          selectInput("Filter1", label = h4("Select just one cluster to show"),""),
                          selectInput("Filter2",label=h4("Select the cluster property designated above"),""),
                          h4("Distance is:"),
                          textOutput("dist"),
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          tabsetPanel(      
                            tabPanel("Solution", (leafletOutput("Leaf",width = "95%", height = "600"))))),
                      ))))

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  Modelcl<-reactive({
    function.cl(df,input$Slider,input$Filter1,input$Filter2)
  })


  output$Leaf <- renderLeaflet({
    Modelcl()[[1]]
  })

  observeEvent(c(df,input$Slider),{
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data)
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter1',
                      choices=c(sort(unique(abc$cluster)))) 
  }) 

  observeEvent(c(df,input$Slider,input$Filter1),{
    abc <- req(Modelcl()$Data1) %>% filter(cluster == as.numeric(input$Filter1))   
    updateSelectInput(session,'Filter2', choices = unique(abc$Industries))
  })

  output$dist <- renderText({
    cover <- data.frame(Modelcl()[[4]])
    cover$Coverage_meters[cover$cluster == input$Filter1]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Great, thanks for the reply. You made a certain friend, but it depends on the selected industry. The image you inserted to show refers to cluster 3 and industry 4, resulting in a distance of 5868,903. However, for cluster 3 there is industry 6 as well. That is, industry 6 has a different location from industry 4. Therefore, it would have to be the distance from industry 6 to the location point of cluster 3.

Comment: I am not sure I follow. `Coverage_meters` between cluster 3 and either of the two industries 4 or 6 is 5868.903. This is the same number in the Coverage matrix for cluster 3 and in the `Data1` data frame  where both rows for cluster 3 are the same.

Comment: Maybe you need to index `Modelcl()$Data1` to find the distance to report?

Comment: It's a great idea, but I don't know how to do it in this case. Do you know?

Comment: You can use the same procedure to filter `Data1`. You want the rows of the table where `Data1$cluster == input$Filter1` and `Data1$Industries == input$Filter2` and then select `Coverage_meters`. See the edit in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I entered the formula you provided but it remained the same distances, right? I tested it now for both industry 4 and industry 6 (cluster 3) the distance to the location point was 5868,903. Am I missing something? because in fact it would have to be different, because properties 4 and 6 have different coordinates.

Comment: This is exactly what I said in my earlier comment. To quote: "Coverage_meters between cluster 3 and either of the two industries 4 or 6 is 5868.903". So it seems your calculation of the distances is the problem, not how to output this number in Shiny.

Comment: Teofil, I inserted the correct code above to calculate the distance between the cluster's location point and the industries of the respective cluster. I did the example for the same cluster we were talking about earlier (cluster 3, industries 4 and 6). Now could you help me try to adjust this to show the correct distances in shiny? Thank you!

Comment: Hi @JovaniSouza, few questions: 1) In your edited code, what is `df` ? Is it the original table or something else? 2) How does this code select the cluster, I only see filtering by industry? 3) When I try the `cluster_mass`  object create inside your function, to use in the distance calculation code from your edit, I get an error related to indexing.

Comment: This entire thread is getting unnecessarily complicated. And is a great example of why SO is encouraging _minimal reproducible examples_ (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In this case, we don't need any of the code for making maps. In fact we might not even need any shiny code. The problem appears to boil down to what you return from the function and how to use those outputs to calculate the distance. You should be able to do this outside shiny first. Only then implement in an interactive mode.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience Teofil. You have already helped me a lot, and I am grateful for that. I hope to resolve this issue soon. If I can I will contact you to talk to you. Thank you again!

Comment: Teofil, I inserted the answer to that question. I used your idea to show the distance value. The only thing I did was how the code would calculate the distance between the cluster location point and the cluster industries ("mydf"). It worked now, thank you very much for your help. If you want to insert it as your answer, I'll accept it.